# Most easyest way of giving remote access with one account to several fodlers, under linux

Tags: linux, remote-access, network-share

We have a new employee, who is not an expert in ssh, but he is a sitebuilder, so we need a proper and secure way to give him REMOTE access to several directories. Is there a secure, easy and convenient way to do so, without creating separate ftp accounts for each directory? Webdav excluded!

System is Debian squeeze
FTP: pure-ftpd

Comment: If a site-builder can't use WinSCP (considering he has problems with SSH it's unlikely he uses anything but windows) I'd look for a different webmaster...

Answer (score 0):

Pure-ftpd allows you to authenticate via the users in your system, so create a new user for the sitebuilder and then modify file permissions accordingly (either put him in a suitable group, or make him the owner of the particular directories and files), he will be able to connect via FTP (which will probably suit what he is familiar with, rather than SSH), and only modify the files he has permissions to edit.

Regards,
Phil,

Comment: FTP is not secure